# How to migrate all product from host 1.9.0 to host 2.0?

Tags: magento2, products, migration

I'm not a technical person, i'm facing with a problem with my Magento site. I have a site Magento 1.9.0 in host and domain A, i want to migrate all products form host + domain A to host and domain B. How i can do it? 
Please help me and thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has tool to migrate from Magento1 to Magento2. Please check following link 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html

You may need technical support to achieve this.

Comment: Thank so much! @Sourabh Modi